# 401 error when downloading file - SharePoint ClientContext

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

For the below CilentContext code to download a document in the client machine. When code hits the OpenBinaryDirect() method i get a unauthorised 401 error.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
                {
                    using (FileInformation sharePointFile = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, serverRelativeUrlOfFile))
                    {
                        using (Stream destFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(fileDestinationPath))
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                            int byteReadInLastRead;
                            while ((byteReadInLastRead = sharePointFile.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                destFile.Write(buffer, 0, byteReadInLastRead);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

any reason why it gives this error ?

Answer (score 0):

@ Shaamil...
It is throwing 401 error because you don't have enough privileges to access the file.
You are creating the SPSite object with the system account but not making use of the extra privileges.

When you use Server Object Model, You can directly create corresponding SPWeb object (where the file is stored)
by using site.OpenWeb("server relative url of your website").
And use that SPWeb object to get the file.

since you are using the system account, you will not have any auth issues. 
In the below case only SPFile object will be access using system account privileges.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("site url",SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
{
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPFile file = (SPFile)web.GetFileOrFolderObject("file_url");
                using (Stream srcFile = file.OpenBinaryStream())
                {
                    using (Stream destFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("C:\\filename.extension"))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                        int byteReadInLastRead;
                        while ((byteReadInLastRead = srcFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            destFile.Write(buffer, 0, byteReadInLastRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If you want to use client object model use as below...
It works only if you know the credentials of the owner(or of the user who has access to the file) level user.
If you know the credentials of any of the Site Collection Admin, that is ultimate.

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password","domain");
clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
```

Then pass this clientContext object as below to get the FileInformation object

```
using(FileInformation sharePointFile = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, serverRelativeUrlOfFile))
{
...
// Do your operation as it is..
...
}
```

I hope it helps you... :)

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you need the following, does't mix `system.io` that reference to File, for some reason the compiler bad compile the code, and to call from the context like this, not use the interface :

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File
File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileRef);
```